# SSIS Execiption: "Could not find stored procedure '##########'......."

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, oledbcommand

I am importing from `ODBC` to `SQL Server`.  I have a `ODBC Source` to `DataConversion` transformation to `OLE DB Command`.  In my sql command I have the following `EXEC` statement:  `EXEC Insert_Adata ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?`.  Everything is setup correctly (as I have been doing this for a while now).  I keep getting the following errorS:

```
-.....The batch could not be analyzed because of compile errors
-.....Could not find stored procedure...
```

I have refreshed everything possible that can be refreshed and even restarted VisualStudio.  I CANNOT get rid of these exceptions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, maybe the connection that you are using is for a database that doesn't have that sp?

Comment: You don't have much useful info in your question. About all I could suggest is looking at all of the common problems, i.e., check connection string, security, etc. -- You claim good knowledge, so I don't know what to suggest you should not already have tried yourself.

Comment: I write these stored procedures everyday...same DB.  I haven't had this problem before

Comment: What happens when you use the full name of the sp:  `[dbname].[schema].Insert_Adata`?  Do you still get an error?

Comment: @EricHauenstein tried that...still get the error

Comment: It apparently is all the stored procedures that are giving me this message.  I'm connected to the right database.  Haven't ever had this problem.  I still can't figure out what is going on.  Everything was working fine yesterday.

Comment: I guess it would of helped if I would of had the fully qualified db name for the ole db connection....duh....smh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that the `OLE DB` connection is set to the fully qualified path to the DB in which the `storedProcedure` is stored or if is not set to fully qualified path, the `[db name].dbo.[storedProcedure]`